# Capitalize First Char Of Words in a string

Tags: c#, performance

I want to format my string into Capitalize character formatting (i.e Capitalize First Char Of Words).

```
For Example - 
              If Input is: "NEW YORK CITY"
              then the desired output is: "New York City"
```

*my string have maximum 3 words.

After, googled it i found several of ways to achieve this approach, but i can't get which is the best approach for this.

**Method 1st:**

```
string City = "NEW YORK CITY";
City = City.ToLower();
string Capatilize_City = "";
Capatilize_City = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(City);
```

[Demo : Ideone with 1st method](http://ideone.com/2DkTRB)

**Method 2nd:**

```
string City = "NEW YORK CITY";
string[] lstWord = City.ToLower().Split(' ');
string Capatilize_City = "";
foreach (string s in lstWord)
{
  string z = s.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + s.Substring(1, s.Length - 1);
  Capatilize_City += " " + z;
}
Capatilize_City = Capatilize_City.Trim();
```

[Demo: Ideone with 2nd method](http://ideone.com/kOf9oz)

Which code is best for use (performance and speed vice)?

Comment: your second method has lots of allocations, so my guess is that it would be slower.  A profiler can give you the data to tell.

Comment: Try to avoid manual. Use method-1. It is also readable and shorter.

Comment: The only way to know which is faster is to test them.  Chances are, both are fast enough, in which case go with the simpler.

Comment: Unless you are trying to title case a copy of "War & Peace" then performance shouldn't be an issue with either method.

Answer (score 5):

You should go for code size, readability, understandability, maintainability, so the clear winner is...

---

**EDIT**

So I'd propose

```
Capatilize_City =
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo
      .ToTitleCase(City.ToLower());
```

Comment: So, in the above case the first method is the best?

Comment: Yes, I think using the criteria in my answer this is **very** obvious

Answer (score 1):

This one liner also works:

```
string Capatilize_City =
    String.Join(
        " ",
        City
            .ToLower()
            .Split(' ')
            .Select(s =>
                s.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()
                + s.Substring(1, s.Length - 1)));
```

Unless you are doing this over a massive string performance shouldn't be an issue for any method.

I'd suggest that you make yourself an extension method on strings called `.ToTitleCase()` and use that - then if you need to change the implementation you can do it in just one spot in your code.

Comment: Why would someone use this instead of the existing ToTitleCase()?

Comment: I wouldn't use it, except for the fact that the OP put forward a semantically equivalent approach. I was just providing a "cleaner" way to approach his method. Also there may be special cases (pardon the pun) - like the acronym issue - that the OP wants to cover and the existing `ToTitleCase()` may not do the right thing for the OP. Why else would he raise this question?